# How to observe a property inside a widget to change a readonly AliasProperty outside it?

Tags: python, kivy

This sample code

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import AliasProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class SampleLayout(BoxLayout):
    def get_something(self):
        return self.sample_widget.width + 30

    something = AliasProperty(get_something, bind=['sample_widget.width'], cache=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sample_widget = Button(on_release=self.sample_test)
        self.add_widget(self.sample_widget)

    def sample_test(self, *args):
        print(self.something)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SampleLayout()


MyApp().run()
```

Returns this error

```py
AttributeError: type object 'SampleLayout' has no attribute 'sample_widget.width'
```

bcs (I guess) `bind` is searching for an attribute of the instance and not an attribute of an attribute of the instance... Maybe with `getattr()` which also doesn't work if using dots in the variable name.

So, is there an API for such bind? or should I bind directly with `self.sample_widget.bind(width=idontknow)`?

If it is the last case, what is that function `idontknow` to call the getter of a (cached) readonly property?

Understand also that the code above is an example, I need this functionality for something more complex. I cannot just put `print(self.sample_widget.width + 30)` under `sample_test` to get it working.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself :)

I don't know if this is the better approach, but works.

```py
    sample_width = NumericProperty()  # an intermediate
...
    something = AliasProperty(get_something, bind=['sample_width'], cache=True)
...
        # sync the intermediate with the wanted var
        self.sample_widget.bind(width=self.setter('sample_width'))
```

so the example code would be like this:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import AliasProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class SampleLayout(BoxLayout):
    def get_something(self):
        return self.sample_widget.width + 30

    sample_width = NumericProperty()  # an intermediate
    something = AliasProperty(get_something, bind=['sample_width'], cache=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sample_widget = Button(on_release=self.sample_test)
        self.add_widget(self.sample_widget)
        # sync the intermediate with the wanted var
        self.sample_widget.bind(width=self.setter('sample_width'))

    def sample_test(self, *args):
        print(self.something)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SampleLayout()


MyApp().run()
```